# In Electron, how to show the parent window on top by clicking?

Tags: electron

When parent window creates a child window, the child window is always on top of the parent window. Clicking one of the sibling windows generated by the same parent window, will make the clicked one on top. But clicking the parent window won't let it show on the top of other child windows. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "win" is the name of your child window - this is added in your main.js or index.js file if you want the window to be focused.

```
win.on('show', () => { win.focus(); });
win.show();
```

Comment: It's not work for me. When I click the parent window, it's still covered by the child windows.